# Unable to find image 'name:latest' locally

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-image

I am trying to run the postgres container and get error as bellow.

```
"Unable to find image 'name:latest' locally

docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for name, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied."
```

I have been working on the problem for a couple of days I do not know what the problem is.

This is of my command:
[image]

Comment: Try to express technically - what commands you are trying to execute , try to provide some basic details before submitting your questions.

Comment: Please add comments and steps as mentioned above and not just an image. It is easier for others to help you if all information is given

Answer (score 8):

Just in case anyone gets this error for the same reason I did. I had built an image locally and Docker was complaining the image could not be found. It seems the error was happening because I built the image locally, but specified a different platform for `docker run` (I had copied the command from somewhere else). Example:

```
docker build -t my-image .
docker run ... --platform=linux/amd64 my-image
```

`linux/amd64` is not my current platform. So I removed this argument and it worked.

Comment: this was happening to me as wel

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your command:

```
docker run -- name
```

While `--name` should be with no any spaces, but you have space between `--` and `name`.

Run your command again with the correct syntax.

To clarify more:

When you run `docker run -- name`, `docker` assumes that you are trying to pull and download an image called `name`, and since your `name` does not include any tags, so it says `I cannot find any image called name:latest`.

Answer (score 1):

Before you pull the image from DockerHub, use `docker login` and then enter your username and password.

If you have not yet registered in DockerHub, register from the link below
[here](https://hub.docker.com/signup)

then you can use this command for pull your images.

```
docker pull imageName
```

be notice that the image you want to receive must already be in DockerHub.

Answer (score 0):

Answer : **You can't use that image because you didn't login to your** [Docker Hub Account](https://hub.docker.com/)

After creating an account find the image you want to use and then pull the image .

You can simply use  `docker pull [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG|@DIGEST]` for pulling an image from docker.hub and the using it as a container

According to the [docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/)

> Most of your images will be created on top of a base image from the Docker Hub registry.
> Docker Hub contains many pre-built images that you can pull and try without needing to define and configure your own.
> To download a particular image, or set of images (i.e., a repository), use docker pull.

P.S : Thank you for contributing in stackoverflow community, but for your next question please ensure that you are asking your question properly by reading 
[Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)